# wireless communication with lifx virtual bulb

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, home-automation-x10

I saw LIFX Virtual Bulb the other day and am curious to know how does this communication take place...

For those who don't know what is [LIFX](http://lifx.co/) - it is a wireless RGB LED bulb which can be controlled via iPhone and Android app. If you don't have a bulb yet, you can go to [www.virtualbulb.lifx.co](http://virtualbulb.lifx.co/), open LIFX app on your phone and control a virtual bulb on your web browser. **To do this, your phone and your laptop on which you have opened virtual bulb webpage should be on the same wifi network. There was NO DIRECT CONNECTION between my iPhone and laptop, both were on the same wifi network.** This is where I started to ponder!!

I know very little about networking. The only thing I can do is setup a modem and wifi router for internet connection.

So, while researching about the above (sentence in **bold**) I came across Zigbee (802.15.4) standard which is widely used in home automation but as the browser was open on my laptop, zigbee is out of question for such kind of communication.

Then I thought about Wifi direct, but as there was no direct connection between my iPhone and laptop and a network was involved that possibility is ruled out as well.

It would be great if someone could enlighten me about this communication protocol and also how the communication takes place between the iPhone/Android device and the REAL LIFX bulb.

Thanks in advance!

A confused geek!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, products like these (including Apple TV and Google Chromecast) use IP [multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast) to communicate. With multicast, you don't need to know the sender's exact IP address, you subscribe to the prearranged multicast address in order to communicate.

In small (home-)networks, this essentially works like broadcast. In large (carrier-)networks, there is a lot you can configure to make this work efficiently.

Comment: @RobinG thanks for the information. this was helpful.